Exclude regex in the rosbag record cmd line not working when used inside a C++ program
I am using a system() call to record a ros bag with a C++ program. The example below works well when called from C++
Example:
int main()
{ 
.
. 
system("rosbag record -a ");
.
.
}

When a exclude regex is added (-x or --exclude) inside C++ does not work, but the same command executed in the terminal works like a charm. Can anyone point where I am going wrong?
std::string temp =  "rosbag record -a -x \"/topic\"";

This would record all topics and not neglect the exclude regex that I have asked for.
I suspect the -x "<>" behaving differently when executed in a terminal and from a program.

Strings can be tricky especially when parsing them around between interpreters. I have no answer to you, but I think you are on the right track. Anyhow, I wanted to ask why would you not consider using the rosbag cpp api?

Well, I am using ros as need by project. In future may be I would use ros2.
There is no way to stop a rosbag record from rosbag::recorder api. I am running multiple rosbag record at any given time so need more control over killing ros record manually.

Oh sorry, I missed that you are referring to ros1. I am pretty sure there is a pretty easy way to stop the recording here. I of course don't want to make any assumptions about your use case. My feeling is telling me though using the api gives you more control than less over suspending a call to rosbag record to a system process.

Hmmm. well  void stopWriting(); is a private member. cannot be access other than class members

You are right, hope I didn't lead you too much down a rabbit hole and glad you figured out a way!

Finally, I figured it out myself. Below is an example code, much needed "<>"(double quotes)for regex can be neglected when used in this way
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {

    ros::init(argc, argv, "~");
    ros::NodeHandle node_handle("~");

    std::vector<std::string> s;
    s.push_back("rosbag");
    s.push_back("record");
    s.push_back("--regex");
    s.push_back("/topic_x(.*)|/topic_y(.*)");
    s.push_back("--exclude");
    s.push_back("/topic_z");
    
    char *myargs[s.size() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        myargs[i] = (char *)s[i].c_str();
    }
    myargs[s.size()] = (char *)0;

    if (verbose)
    {
        for ( const auto&s_:myargs)
        {
            std::cout<<s_<<std::endl;
        }
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (0 == pid)
    {
        // In child process
        if (-1 == execvp("rosbag", myargs))
        {
            ROS_INFO("exec failure %d", errno);
        }
        else
        {
            // ROS_INFO_STREAM("PID : "<<_rec_pid);
        }
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        // In parent process
        if (verbose)
            ROS_INFO("----Bag Recording Started ----");
    }

